# Flutter listview moving when loading images from network

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

i am trying to make a listview with lots of images with different dimensions loaded from network.
When I scroll down everything is okay, but when i am scrolling up, first images start to load changing the position of listview. I suppose I need to have a placeholder for images with height of image, but i dont know how to get their dimensions before them loaded. Or i need smth like listview that does not move because of smth upper loading.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  Having the same problem, and haven't been able to solve it after a few weeks now..

Comment: Yeah, I actually did. I will post an answer today. It's a little bit tricky, and in first load image still has zero size, but after image loads for the first time, it's gonna have a placeholder, so scrolling will be okay

Comment: Posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function that gets a height of image in a cycle (array favorites contains Maps which contain url parameter and height parameter if loaded). The function also converts image's height in the size i actually need by formula with MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 80 which is the width of images on screen. (Width of the screen minus 40 padding from each side).

This is the code of getting height function:

```
Future<void> getImageHeight(String url, index) async {
    Image image = Image.network(url);
    image.image
        .resolve(const ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool isSync) {
      favorites[index]['height'] = info.image.height *
          ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 80) / info.image.width);
      setState(() {});
    }));
}
```

And this is the code of image with placeholder (Container):

```
Container(
    color: const Color(0xffE8E6EA),
    height: favorites[index]['height'] == null || favorites[index
            ['height'].isNaN ? 0: favorites[index]['height'],
    child: Image.network(
        favorites[index]['url'],
            width: double.infinity,
    ),
),
```

On first loading size of placeholder is still going to be zero, because it takes time to get height of them. But after few time (it usually takes about a second or less) setState is going to be called and images will not lag on scrolling. And if you are loading your images urls from database not all at once you'll need to rerun function to get height of newly added images.

Comment: Thank you for posting this!  If I am understanding this solution properly, the layout will still move on the very first time an image is loaded from the network, because you do not know the size, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Set minCacheExtend large enough
(to be higher than the highest picture's height)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If images are not big this might work, but I suppose if weight of images is big, cache is going to weight too much

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I resolved it by Increasing the cache of the flutter app. Default cache size is 100mb. You can place this at the beginning of **main.dart**

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
PaintingBinding.instance!.imageCache!.maximumSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 300; // 300 MB
```

More [Info Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68700#issuecomment-925466370)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this solution, but it just increases number of images that user can scroll before the bug appears. If there are lots of images, you need to increase cache too much which is not really good for size of the app.